# Application crash logs in Play Console

Tags: java, android

My application is on Play Store and shows 2 major crashes that I could not find any information about. The crashes do not show up in Crashlytics. As far as I understand, the problem is not in my code, but perhaps some mismatch with the Google dependencies in my project.

1st crash log, sometimes the cache_xxxx numbers are different:

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 0000000000021dcc  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+124)
  #01  pc 000000000046f6d8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+1208)
  #02  pc 0000000000008d2c  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+724)
  #03  pc 00000000002eddf8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::AddGlobalRef(art::Thread*, art::ObjPtr<art::mirror::Object>)+304)
  #04  pc 0000000000335f54  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI::NewGlobalRef(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+612)
  #05  pc 0000000000495714  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateNativeThread(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, unsigned long, bool)+292)
  #06  pc 00000000003e8734  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread_nativeCreate(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jobject*, long, unsigned char)+156)
  #07  pc 000000000011c9cc  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate+188)
  #08  pc 000000000025d694  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.lang.Thread.start+148)
  #09  pc 0000000000080d0c  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache_9320_9320 (deleted)
```

2nd crash log:

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 0000000000021dcc  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+124)
  #01  pc 000000000046f6d8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+1208)
  #02  pc 0000000000008d2c  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+724)
  #03  pc 00000000002eddf8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::AddGlobalRef(art::Thread*, art::ObjPtr<art::mirror::Object>)+304)
  #04  pc 0000000000335f54  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI::NewGlobalRef(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+612)
  #05  pc 000000000013ac24  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (JavaBBinder::JavaBBinder(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+148)
  #06  pc 0000000000139bc4  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (JavaBBinderHolder::get(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+116)
  #07  pc 0000000000139a90  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::ibinderForJavaObject(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+128)
  #08  pc 000000000012ca84  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::android_os_Parcel_writeStrongBinder(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, long, _jobject*)+60)
  #09  pc 000000000041e5f4  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.admin.SecurityLog.readEventsOnWrapping [DEDUPED]+180)
  #10  pc 0000000000b30f28  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Parcel.writeStrongBinder+56)
  #11  pc 00000000001e44c0  /data/app/com.MZAlert-QC6ijjL3rji1BR9uNJapFQ==/oat/arm64/base.odex (com.google.android.gms.internal.location.zzaz.zza+848)
  #12  pc 00000000001e4990  /data/app/com.MZAlert-QC6ijjL3rji1BR9uNJapFQ==/oat/arm64/base.odex (com.google.android.gms.internal.location.zzbl.doExecute+128)
  #13  pc 00000000001be46c  /data/app/com.MZAlert-QC6ijjL3rji1BR9uNJapFQ==/oat/arm64/base.odex (com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BaseImplementation$ApiMethodImpl.run+172)
  #14  pc 0000000000188b10  /data/app/com.MZAlert-QC6ijjL3rji1BR9uNJapFQ==/oat/arm64/base.odex (com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zae.zaa+80)
  #15  pc 00000000001c0348  /data/app/com.MZAlert-QC6ijjL3rji1BR9uNJapFQ==/oat/arm64/base.odex (com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.zac+152)
  #16  pc 00000000001bf1f8  /data/app/com.MZAlert-QC6ijjL3rji1BR9uNJapFQ==/oat/arm64/base.odex (com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.zab+136)
  #17  pc 00000000001c0de0  /data/app/com.MZAlert-QC6ijjL3rji1BR9uNJapFQ==/oat/arm64/base.odex (com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.zaa+432)
  #18  pc 00000000000fcea8  /data/app/com.MZAlert-QC6ijjL3rji1BR9uNJapFQ==/oat/arm64/base.odex (com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager.handleMessage+4440)
  #19  pc 0000000000b210b8  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+136)
  #20  pc 0000000000b241e0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Looper.loop+1264)
  #21  pc 0000000000b23084  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.HandlerThread.run+548)
  #22  pc 0000000000561988  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+584)
  #23  pc 00000000000cff40  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)
  #24  pc 0000000000467d60  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)
  #25  pc 0000000000468e28  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue*)+424)
  #26  pc 00000000004946b0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1120)
  #27  pc 0000000000084df8  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+208)
  #28  pc 0000000000023ac4  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
```

the dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'  // 'com.android.support:design:+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Would much appreciate if anyone could help.

Comment: Did you solve this? Were the devices crashing Samsung devices by any chance?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: And yes, the devices were of Samsung manufacturer.

Comment: It has been some time. Did you solve the issue?

Comment: Nope. I gave up on my dream and started working for a corporation :)